# How to trace errors when using `anyhow`

Tags: rust, error-handling

When using the [anyhow crate](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/) errors can be conveniently bubbled up to the root of the app, where they are handled.

Sometimes, however, I want to know where the error happened and I can't find a way to do that with `anyhow`.

My backtrace only mentions the root:

```
   4: mp_parser::main
             at ./src/main.rs:37:5
```

And running `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` gives me a detailed stack of internal calls, but it doesn't show me where the error originated inside my own code.

As a result I'm often left uncommenting different parts of the code to figure out where the error actually took place.

Is there some way to get the original line where it occured?

Comment: use snafu or thiserror and do proper error design, anyhow is evil (IMO)

Comment: maybe you can try activate the feature `features = ["backtrace"]`

Comment: @Stargateur If you develop a library, `anyhow` is not a (complete) solution. But for a binary, could you elaborate why you find it "evil"?

Comment: I have just tested the `features = ["backtrace"]` setting `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` and it just works!

Comment: @rodrigo What exactly do you mean by "it works"? Did you manage to get the line numbers under *release* mode?

Comment: @at54321: Well, in _release_ mode it just shows the name of the functions. I've just tried setting `debug = true` to `[profile.release]` and it gives also the line numbers. As good as can be expected, I guess.

Comment: @Stargateur `features = ["backtrace"]` worked! Want to add a reply and I'll mark it as correct?

Answer (score 13):

I ran a few tests with the following app (all in **release** mode):

```
use anyhow::{ensure, Result};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    aa()?;
    Ok(())
}

fn aa() -> Result<()> {
    bb(33)?;
    bb(77)?;
    bb(5)?;
    Ok(())
}

fn bb(p: i32) -> Result<i32> {
    ensure!(p >= 10, "param not big enough!");
    Ok(p)
}
```

I tested various combinations:

- On Stable (1.58) and Nightly (1.60) toolchains.
- With and without the "backtrace" feature;
- Without setting `RUST_BACKTRACE` and setting it to `1` or `full` (there was no difference between `1` and `full` in this test).

When running the app with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` or `RUST_BACKTRACE=full`, we get a backtrace like this:

```
Error: param not big enough!

Stack backtrace:
   0: anyhow::error::<impl anyhow::Error>::msg
   1: an::main
   2: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace
   3: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
   4: core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once
             at /rustc/5e57faa78aa7661c6000204591558f6665f11abc/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:259:13
   5: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/5e57faa78aa7661c6000204591558f6665f11abc/library/std/src/panicking.rs:485:40
   6: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/5e57faa78aa7661c6000204591558f6665f11abc/library/std/src/panicking.rs:449:19
   7: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/5e57faa78aa7661c6000204591558f6665f11abc/library/std/src/panic.rs:136:14
   8: std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/5e57faa78aa7661c6000204591558f6665f11abc/library/std/src/rt.rs:128:48
   9: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/5e57faa78aa7661c6000204591558f6665f11abc/library/std/src/panicking.rs:485:40
  10: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/5e57faa78aa7661c6000204591558f6665f11abc/library/std/src/panicking.rs:449:19
  11: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/5e57faa78aa7661c6000204591558f6665f11abc/library/std/src/panic.rs:136:14
  12: std::rt::lang_start_internal
             at /rustc/5e57faa78aa7661c6000204591558f6665f11abc/library/std/src/rt.rs:128:20
  13: main
  14: __libc_start_main
  15: _start
```

I also tested with the "backtrace" feature on:

```
    anyhow = { version = "1.0.52", features = ["backtrace"] }
```

, but that didn't seem to add any valuable information to the stack trace.

The reason we only see `1: an::main` is that in this simple program the other functions are inlined.

We can experiment with disabling inlining for a particular function like this:

```
#[inline(never)]
fn aa() -> Result<()> {...
```

Now we get this:

```
Stack backtrace:
   0: anyhow::error::<impl anyhow::Error>::msg
   1: an::aa
   2: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace
   ...
```

That might help a bit in narrowing down the location where the error originated to a single function, but it is still far from perfect. And, obviously, it's generally not a great idea to disable inlining just for this purpose.

It seems we can do this though:

```
ensure!(p >= 10, "param not big enough! {}:{}", file!(), line!());
```

And even in release mode we can obtain info about the file & line:

```
Error: param not big enough! src/main.rs:18
```

So obviously, it *is* possible to build something around that, but I'm not familiar with how exactly those macros work and how much the overhead would be. Would be happy if someone could shed more light on that.

---

As suggested by Rodrigo, I also tried this:

```
[profile.release]
debug = true
```

The result looks great:

```
Stack backtrace:
   0: anyhow::error::<impl anyhow::Error>::msg
             at /home/xyz/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/anyhow-1.0.52/src/error.rs:79:36
   1: an::bb
             at ./src/main.rs:18:5
   2: an::aa
             at ./src/main.rs:13:2
   3: an::main
             at ./src/main.rs:6:2
   4: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/5e57faa78aa7661c6000204591558f6665f11abc/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:227:5
   5: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace
             at /rustc/5e57faa78aa7661c6000204591558f6665f11abc/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:123:18
   ...
```

The binary size grew up by 16% as a result of this.

Setting `debug = 1` yields the same stack-trace as `debug = true` (which BTW is the same as `debug = 2`), but with only 6% bigger binary size, compared to the default `debug = 0`

I haven't tested if/how that setting affects performance.

Comment: I wonder if enabling stack trace would do any great harm to performance. Maybe we should set it on by default for debug builds.