# Do I have to use an entire match block in Rust to print the error?

Tags: rust, error-handling

Using `?` at the end of functions is a common idiom in Rust. Using this abstracts away the result and error. So do I have to use an entire `match` block to access the `Result`?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking and the code does not seem very relevant. Have you read section 9.2 of the book, specifically [alternatives to using `match`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#alternatives-to-using-match-with-resultt-e)?

Comment: I posted code because that is one of the rules of SO. I tried one of the alternatives in your link and the third-party create does not implement `unwrap_or_else`. Thank you for at least wanting to be helpful. It's a breath of fresh air from soon-to-be-disrupted-by-AI StackOverflow.

Comment: "I posted code because that is one of the rules of SO." posting useful code which demonstrates the issue is what's useful, posting code which doesn't seem very relevant, less so.

Comment: All I want to do is find out what the error says. I just want to be able to access a single part of this error struct in a third-party crate.

Comment: "I tried one of the alternatives in your link and the third-party create does not implement unwrap_or_else." that doesn't make much sense, [`unwrap_or_else` is an intrisinc method of the Result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or_else), that would mean the third-party crates is not using results in the first place.

Comment: I am new to Rust so maybe I missed it. My IDE says it doesn't have this method and I don't see a mention of this method here in this crate's docs: https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/latest/tokio_postgres/error/struct.DbError.html All I want to do is insert some rows to Postgres and get an error if it doesn't work.

Comment: If that's the type you have, you already got the error out of the result. You can just format out the error (e.g. `eprintln!("{:?}", the_thing)` or `the_thing.to_string()`), or use the methods listed if you want something more specific or want more control over the formatting.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.inspect_err

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to do something with the error (like printing/logging it) in the same function, first you shouldn't use `?` - that way you'll get a `Result`. Then you could use a `match`, an `if let Err(e)` or something like that, in order to be able to print the error.

Note that in many real-world cases, an error would be logged somewhere in a more-central place, so you don't always need to print the error in-place. That could make the code less verbose. You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70790176/15602349), as it is somewhat relevant to the question of logging errors (which seems to be your case).